# Loading custom fonts to PDF document not working

Tags: pdfbox

We are converting a PDF document to HTML. Most of the documents are using Courier Final Draft font. The converted html is not getting rendered properly as the text is getting overlapped. Looks like PDFBox is not finding the font and so it is wrongly calculating the spacing between the words. We are trying to load the font (Courier Final Draft) to PDDocument. But is it still not identifying the font. We are getting error as "Error loading font 'Error loading font 'NOLUXZ+CourierFinalDraft". Can somebody guide me on this? Thanks

I tried to load the font as below -

```
            PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
            PDTrueTypeFont.load(doc, ResourceUtils.getFile(
                    "classpath:fonts/Courier_Final_Draft_Regular.ttf"), MacRomanEncoding.INSTANCE);
            PDType0Font.load(doc, ResourceUtils.getFile(
                    "classpath:fonts/Courier_Final_Draft_Regular.ttf"));
            PDType0Font.load(doc, new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(
                    "classpath:fonts/Courier_Final_Draft_Regular.ttf")), false);
```

Comment: Your code is weird, the assignments are missing; and why are you constructing a new PDDocument?

Comment: We are constructing new PDDocument because we are separating each page of the PDF in a separate document as we are saving each page separately